# Checking and reviewing previous grouped values within groups in R

Tags: r, tidyverse, data-wrangling

I have a small dataset of 4 variables one is `subject` the second is `key` which is a code that a subject uses to log onto a system, third is `order` which will keep track of chronological year  and finally the variable `Period` that indicates whether the key was used in a previous time `past` or the current month `current`.

This is the dataset:

```
subjects<-c(rep("James",3),
            rep("Alex",2),
            rep("Mila",8),
            rep("Mark",1))

keys<-c(rep("IX08-8",2),"IX08-8",
        "UX-007","HH-011",rep("PO_85",7),"UJ_8","785_PO")
order<-c(1:14)
period<-c("past","past","current","past","current",rep("past",6),"current","current","current")
df<-cbind(subjects,keys,period,order)  

> head(df)
     subjects keys     period    order
[1,] "James"  "IX08-8" "past"    "1"  
[2,] "James"  "IX08-8" "past"    "2"  
[3,] "James"  "IX08-8" "current" "3"  
[4,] "Alex"   "UX-007" "past"    "4"  
[5,] "Alex"   "HH-011" "current" "5"  
[6,] "Mila"   "PO_85"  "past"    "6"
```

Ultimately I have to be able to tell if a subject is using a previously used `key` to log onto the system in the `current` Period. If a `subject` uses a new `key` to log onto the system in the current `period` then I will assign the value "1" to a column named `result`, if the user did not use a previously used `key` to log onto the system during the current `period` the value assigned should be "0" and "NA" otherwise.

My desired output would look like this:

```
      subjects keys     period    order result
 [1,] "James"  "IX08-8" "past"    "1"   NA    
 [2,] "James"  "IX08-8" "past"    "2"   NA    
 [3,] "James"  "IX08-8" "current" "3"   "0"   
 [4,] "Alex"   "UX-007" "past"    "4"   NA    
 [5,] "Alex"   "HH-011" "current" "5"   "1"   
 [6,] "Mila"   "PO_85"  "past"    "6"   NA    
 [7,] "Mila"   "PO_85"  "past"    "7"   NA    
 [8,] "Mila"   "PO_85"  "past"    "8"   NA    
 [9,] "Mila"   "PO_85"  "past"    "9"   NA    
[10,] "Mila"   "PO_85"  "past"    "10"  NA    
[11,] "Mila"   "PO_85"  "past"    "11"  NA    
[12,] "Mila"   "PO_85"  "current" "12"  "0"   
[13,] "Mila"   "UJ_8"   "current" "13"  "1"   
[14,] "Mark"   "785_PO" "current" "14"  "1"
```

For instance, in row # 3 James has assigned value 0 in result because he has used a previously used key to log on to the system in the current month which was key "IX08-8", but Mark has a value of 1 in the result column because the system has only tracked one key and that happens to be the key that he used to log on this current period which is technically a "new key".

**Here is what I have done to solve this:**

I can group the dataset by `subject` and make sure this is arrange by `order` in a descending manner, but I can only think about creating a vector of keys (`vector.of.previous.keys`) per subject based on (`period="past"`) and then evaluate if the current key is `%in%` `vector.of.previous.keys`, but if there is a way to only check within groups this criteria it would be a lot more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data is stored in a data.frame

```r
df <- data.frame(subjects,keys,period,order)
```

you could use

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(subjects, keys) %>% 
  mutate(count = row_number()) %>% 
  group_by(subjects) %>% 
  mutate(result = case_when(period == "current" & count == 1 ~ 1,
                            period == "current" & count >= 1 ~ 0,
                            TRUE ~ NA_real_)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-count)
```

to get

```r
# A tibble: 14 x 5
   subjects keys   period  order result
   <chr>    <chr>  <chr>   <int>  <dbl>
 1 James    IX08-8 past        1     NA
 2 James    IX08-8 past        2     NA
 3 James    IX08-8 current     3      0
 4 Alex     UX-007 past        4     NA
 5 Alex     HH-011 current     5      1
 6 Mila     PO_85  past        6     NA
 7 Mila     PO_85  past        7     NA
 8 Mila     PO_85  past        8     NA
 9 Mila     PO_85  past        9     NA
10 Mila     PO_85  past       10     NA
11 Mila     PO_85  past       11     NA
12 Mila     PO_85  current    12      0
13 Mila     UJ_8   current    13      1
14 Mark     785_PO current    14      1
```

Answer (score 2):

Another `dplyr` method here, where all of your conditions are coded in a `case_when` statement.

#### Code

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(subjects) %>% 
  mutate(result = case_when(period == "current" & n() == 1 ~ "1",
                            period == "current" & keys == first(keys) ~ "0",
                            period == "current" & keys != first(keys) & n() > 1 ~ "1",
                            period == "past" ~ NA_character_,
                            TRUE == "past" ~ NA_character_))
# A tibble: 14 × 5
# Groups:   subjects [4]
   subjects keys   period  order result
   <chr>    <chr>  <chr>   <int> <chr> 
 1 James    IX08-8 past        1 NA    
 2 James    IX08-8 past        2 NA    
 3 James    IX08-8 current     3 0     
 4 Alex     UX-007 past        4 NA    
 5 Alex     HH-011 current     5 1     
 6 Mila     PO_85  past        6 NA    
 7 Mila     PO_85  past        7 NA    
 8 Mila     PO_85  past        8 NA    
 9 Mila     PO_85  past        9 NA    
10 Mila     PO_85  past       10 NA    
11 Mila     PO_85  past       11 NA    
12 Mila     PO_85  current    12 0     
13 Mila     UJ_8   current    13 1     
14 Mark     785_PO current    14 1
```

#### data

Note that I've changed your `cbind()` to `data.frame` (data frame is easier to work with compared to matrix).

```
subjects<-c(rep("James",3),
            rep("Alex",2),
            rep("Mila",8),
            rep("Mark",1))

keys<-c(rep("IX08-8",2),"IX08-8",
        "UX-007","HH-011",rep("PO_85",7),"UJ_8","785_PO")
order<-c(1:14)
period<-c("past","past","current","past","current",rep("past",6),"current","current","current")
df<-data.frame(subjects,keys,period,order)
```

Comment: Hey @benson23 thank you for your quick reply, you are quite talented, could you please let me know if by using "first" would be just comparing the very first element of the group with the current one? thank you so much

Comment: @R_Student Yes you’re right. See more [here](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/nth.html)